# How to enter data from json array file when multiple array present in json file using java

Tags: java, json, selenium, testng

I am reading input data from json file. My json file structure is

```
`{  "testloginpage":[
                    {
                    "username":"hellotest",
                    "password":"password1234",
                    },          
                ],  "emailtest":[
                        {
                        "fromemailaddress":"noreply@test.com",
                        "testemailserver":"111.11.11.1",
                        "testusername":"test",
                        "testpassword":"test",
                        },
                        {
                        "fromemailaddress":"aaaa@test.com",
                        "testemailserver":"22.22.22.2",
                        "testusername":"aaaa",
                        "testpassword":"aaaa",
                        },      ],

}`
```

I am able to loop thru and able to read all data by using the following code:

```
public static void readFromJson() {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try{
            FileReader reader = new FileReader ("<--FilePath--><filenale>.json.txt");
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
            JSONArray login = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("testloginpage");
            for (int i = 0; i<login.size();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObjectRow = (JSONObject) login.get(i);
                UserName = (String) jsonObjectRow.get("username");
                Password = (String) jsonObjectRow.get("password");
                }
            JSONArray emailtestfields = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("emailtest");
                    for ( i = 0; i<emailtestfields.size();i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println("The "+i+" elements in email test are" +emailtestfields.get(i));
                    }
                    Iterator i = emailtestfields.iterator();
                    while (i.hasNext()){
                        JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) i.next();
                        System.out.println("From email address is "+innerObj.get("fromemailaddress"));
                        fromEmailAddressEmailSettings = (String) innerObj.get("fromemailaddress");
                        System.out.println("test Email Server is  "+innerObj.get("testemailserver"));
                        emailServerEmailSettings = (String) innerObj.get("testemailserver");
                        System.out.println("User name is "+innerObj.get("testusername"));
                        testUserNameEmailSettings = (String) innerObj.get("testusername");
                        System.out.println("test User password is "+innerObj.get("testuserpassword"));
                        testPasswordEmailSettings = (String) innerObj.get("testpassword");
                    }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+e);
        }
}
```

I have a testng class where I m creating test script. Currently script is entering only second set of data into the form and saving it. 
The scenario I am trying to achieve is I have to read from json as how many set of records for emailtest are available (in eg its 2) and than in my testng class I have to first take first set of emailtest data and enter and save and than take second set and enter in web app and save. I have created generic function to enter data into the textbox which are working good. I dont know how can i carry the loop count into my testng test script and than first enter the first data set and save and than take second set, enter and save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the json format to 
    {
    "appLogin":{
            "userName":"test",
            "password":"test",
            },

```
        "createNewUser":{
        "UserName":["test1", "test2"],
        "UserPassword":["solution1","solution2"], 
        "UserConfirmPassword":["solution1","solution2"],
        "UserFirstName":["testuser1","testuser2"], 
        "UserLastName":["test1","Hello2"], 
        "UserGroup":"localuser",
        },
}
```

And this is the java code I am using

```
static String userName;
static String password;
static String newUserNames[];
static String newUserPasswords[];
static String newUserConfirmPasswords[];
static String newUserFirstNames[];
static String newUserLastNames[];
static String userGroup[];
Public static void readFile() {
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("<<Location of ur input json data file>>"));
jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
/**
* This section is to read login data from input json file.
*/
JSONObject gveLogin = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("appLogin");
userName = (String) gveLogin.get("userName");
password = (String) gveLogin.get("password");
/**
* This section is to read create new user from input json file.
*/
JSONObject createNewUser = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("createNewUser");
JSONArray newUserName = null;
Object newUserNameObj = (createNewUser !=   null &&     
createNewUser.containsKey("UserName")) ? createNewUser.get("UserName") : null;
if (newUserNameObj !=null && newUserNameObj instanceof JSONArray){
newUserName = (JSONArray) newUserNameObj;
}
int newUserNameSize = newUserName.size();
newUserNames = new String[newUserNameSize];
int newUserNameCount;
for (newUserNameCount = 0;newUserNameCount<newUserNameSize; newUserNameCount++){
newUserNames [newUserNameCount] = (String) newUserName.get(newUserNameCount);
System.out.println(newUserNames[newUserNameCount]);
}
.... Same for password, confirm password, first name , last name and for userGroup I have used jsonObject as follows:
newUserGroup = (String) createNewUser.get("userGroup");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save both the JSONObject in an List and pass that to your data entering method eg

```
List<JSONObject> lst = new ArrayList..
while (i.hasNext()){
JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) i.next();
lst.add(innerObj);
}

for (Jsonobject a : lst) {
  putindata(a);
}

public void putindata(JsonObject a) {
   //sendKeys(a.getString("fromemailaddress");
   //...
}
```